# Python ldap3 - LDAPStartTLSError: startTLS failed - unavailable

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap3

I want to use ldap3 with python 3.9 to connect and update my password from MS AD.

```
server = Server('my_server')
conn = Connection(server, USER, PASS, authentication=NTLM)
conn.bind()
conn.start_tls()
```

The `conn.bind()` is True, but when I do the `conn.start_tls()` I got this error:

```
Nico/Documents/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py in start_tls(self, read_server_info)
   1312                 if self.closed:
   1313                     self.open()
-> 1314                 if self.server.tls.start_tls(self) and self.strategy.sync:  # for asynchronous connections _start_tls is run by the strategy
   1315                     if read_server_info:
   1316                         self.refresh_server_info()  # refresh server info as per RFC4515 (3.1.5)

Nico/Documents/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ldap3/core/tls.py in start_tls(self, connection)
    275                 if log_enabled(ERROR):
    276                     log(ERROR, '%s for <%s>', connection.last_error, connection)
--> 277                 raise LDAPStartTLSError(connection.last_error)
    278             if log_enabled(BASIC):
    279                 log(BASIC, 'tls started for <%s>', connection)

LDAPStartTLSError: startTLS failed - unavailable
```

My `conn.result`:

```
{'result': 52,
 'description': 'unavailable',
 'dn': '',
 'message': '00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C0912C4, comment: Error initializing SSL/TLS, data 0, v3839\x00',
 'referrals': None,
 'responseName': '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037',
 'responseValue': b'',
 'type': 'extendedResp'}
```

If I try to do `server = Server('my_server', use_ssl=True)` then, I'm not able to do `conn.bind()`

```
LDAPSocketOpenError: socket ssl wrapping error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a plain username or a Distinguished Name (DN)? Did you try setting auto-bind to true when setting the connection?

Comment: I'm using a plain username: user="Domain\\User". I've tried auto-bind when settings the connection and It worked, but the problem is the `conn.result` that is throwing the error I posted.

Comment: You might need to use a Distinguished Name for the Username, e.g. `CN=Jeff Smith,OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/distinguished-names

Comment: Well.. The solution was try with another server that supports LDAP and LDAPS. Also I needed the DN to change the password for my AD.
Now I can connect to my sv using port `389` and then make a `conn.start_tls()`